# Nonetype error not fixed by if-else condition text scraping BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am currently trying to extract the text of articles from multiple RSS feeds that come from one site. I've written a code that collects the urls for these multiple RSS feeds from the RSS page, then collects the url for articles from individual RSS feeds. The code then tries to extract the text from each unique article url. But here I am running into difficulties.

My extract text function returns the error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'. However, I have placed in an if/else condition to attempt to deal with NoneTypes.

Why is the attribute error occurring even when there is an if-condition to circumvent it?

Here is a minimal reproducible example using Newspaper3k to get urls as opposed to RSS feeds. Please let me know how I can further clarify or correct my question.

```py
#Libraries to be used
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import newspaper as np

#function to extract text from url
def extract_text(url_list):  
    art_list = []
    for url in url_list:
        page = requests.get(url)
        if page is not None: #This is not working
            urlsoup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
            if urlsoup is not None: #This did not fix
                text = urlsoup.find('div', id='article-content').text
                art_list.append(text)
        else:
            art_list.append('')
    return art_list

#get set of articles
voa_chinese = np.build('https://www.voachinese.com/', 
                       language='zh', memoize_articles=False)

#get set of urls
url_list = []

for article in voa_chinese.articles:
    url_list.append(article.url)

#Run function on url list
article_list = extract_text(url_list)
```

Here is the error message:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-251a9e599cc9> in <module>()
      8     url_list.append(article.url)
      9 
---> 10 article_list = extract_text(url_list)

<ipython-input-25-0fa49893d593> in extract_text(url_list)
     14             urlsoup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
     15             if urlsoup is not None:
---> 16                 text = urlsoup.find('div', id='article-content').text
     17                 art_list.append(text)
     18         else:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Comment: please [edit] your question and limit your question to specific question. also provide your code as a `code` instead of `img`, as well with provide a [mcve]

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη Thank you for the help properly formatting my question. I hope this is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing this:

```
if urlsoup is not None: #This did not fix
    text = urlsoup.find('div', id='article-content').text
    art_list.append(text)
```

to something like

```
if urlsoup is not None: 
    item = urlsoup.find('div', id='article-content')
    if item.text is not None:
       art_list.append(item.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use try catch as an alternative:

```
try:
   text = urlsoup.find('div', id='article-content').text
except:
   text = "Not Found "    #or do something as desired
```